# After update the KDE login no longer is displayed, but a blank screen

Tags: nvidia, kernel, updates, xorg, kde

I just did an update and the only thing that was in it was an update to the kernel. The new kernel is 5.8.0-45 and the old was 5.8.0-44.

After this update, all things Xorg and KDE stopped working, there is no login screen, but I can log in from another computer.

`sddm` is running but as I said above nothing Xorg or KDE related is running. There are no errors in any error log that I can find. I looked at both `dmesg` and `syslog`. The Xorg.0.log has not updated since the first reboot after the update.

So it looks like it's an issue with `Xorg` not starting, but why is the issue.

I don't know if this is a one-off issue with me only or a bug in the updated kernel code.

Any insights would be appreciated like how could I reconfigure `Xorg` to start.

The only thing I can add to this is that I have a Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: Can you bring up the GRUB screen and boot into the old kernel?

Comment: NO, there is no list of old kernels. All I get after the BIOS message is a blinking cursor that goes away in a second, then nothing.
I can't even go to a terminal Ctl F1 - 6 does nothing. I can only ssh into the box.

Comment: OK, the reason I could pick a different kernel is that grub wasn't configured for it. Duh
I've now fixed that and I was able to login now with the old kernel.

I'm going to try to reinstall the new kernel to see if it didn't install properly.

Comment: Good news! There may just be some bug in the new kernel.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got everything working with the latest kernel. This is what I did:

1. Enabled the grub boot list by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

2. Booted into the last working kernel.
3. Logged out then back in choosing the latest kernel. This worked but I had to reboot at the command line because the GUI logout kept crashing.
4. Logged in again letting grub choose the default (latest kernel) and it worked this time. The GUI logout also worked.
5. It looks like `/boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic` was regenerated. I'm betting this is where the problem was.

Comment: You don't mention the command you used to reinstall the new kernel.

Comment: I never reinstalled the new kernel. The kernel came in as an update yesterday. What I did was manually chose the previous kernel then manually chose the latest kernel and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Same problem here. I resolved it exactly the same way - choosing older kernel did the job. I've tried to remove the new kernel but it didn't work - dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic
I'll wait if some proper solution popups.

Comment: One more thing - I don't think it's related to nVidia. I've got AMD rx580 with the same problem.